# Sending axios.post login method stuck in preflight - no response data

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, axios, cors

I'm developing an app using the following technologies:

Client-Side: React, TypeScript, Axios

Server-side: Node, Express, CORS (https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors)

I'm having trouble testing my login endpoint locally - http://localhost:8080/api/users

The following is my API code:

```
import express from "express";
import cors from "cors";
import { connectToDB } from "./connections/mongodb";

import { app as appRouter } from "./routes/api";

connectToDB();
dotenv.config();

if (!process.env.PORT) {
  process.exit(1);
}
const PORT: number = parseInt(process.env.PORT as string, 10);

const app = express();
// const corsOptions = {
//   credentials: true,
//   origin: "*",
//   optionsSuccessStatus: 200,
// };
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());
app.use("/api", appRouter);

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Listening on port ${PORT}`);
});
```

Note: As a solution to this problem, I tried passing the corsOptions when I initiate `app.use(cors())` but it didn't seem to help.

The following is my client code:

```
  const data = await axios.post(
    "http://localhost:8080/api/users",
    credentials,
    {
      headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
    }
  );
  return data;
}
```

Now I'd expect this endpoint to return a User object with my auth token, a bit like postman does when I send this request (see screenshot)

[Postman response for login endpoint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1RLME.png)

Please find below the controller method that deals with this request:

```
  try {
    const { email, password } = req.body;
    if (!(email && password)) {
      res.status(400).send("All input is required");
    }

    const user = await UserService.find(email);

    const encryptedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(password, 10);

    const auth = await bcrypt.compare(password, user!.password);

    if (user && auth) {
      const token = jwt.sign(
        { user_id: user._id, email },
        TOKEN_KEY as Secret,
        {
          expiresIn: "2h",
        }
      );

      user.token = token;

      res.status(200).json(user);
    }
    res.status(400).send("Invalid Credentials");
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
};
```

Unfortunately sending this request from my local client doesn't return the data I need for authentication, I just get the following requests in my network tab

[Preflight request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/At9uT.png)

[Options request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b4fqv.png)

Some help would be much appreciated. Can't see where I'm going wrong. I thought the `cors` package amends the request headers to deal with this...

Answer (score -1):

Do you have proxy in your client package.json ?

If no, you want to do:

```
  "proxy": "http://localhost:8000"
```